# Does $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y)\,dx = 0$ imply $\int_{[0,1]^2} f = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I always believed that $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y)\,dx = 0$ (for all $y$) implies $\int_{[0,1]^2} f = 0$ by Fubini-Tonelli.
However, in this upvoted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93865/false-beliefs-about-lebesgue-measure-on-mathbbr/1614151#1614151) it says the opposite.

> So in particular, you shouldn't believe that $\int_{[0,1]^2} f = 0$ follows from $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y)\,dx = 0$ for *every* $y$ and $\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y)\,dy = 0$ for *every* $x$ (take $f$ to be the characteristic function of this $E$).

Can someone clarify?

Comment: I think the function in that answer is not measurable on $[0,1]^{2}$, so the integral over $[0,1]^{2}$ is not defined.

Comment: But he said $f$ is the characteristic function of $E$. So if $f$ wasn't measureable then $E$ wouldn't be measurable a measurable set right? So how can $E$ have positive measure then?

Comment: From that article: "Edit: It is worth noting that the pathologic behaviour is due to the resulting sets not being measurable. For measurable sets such things cannot happen due to Fubini's Theorem."

Comment: So this means $E$ is not a measurable set and only has positive Lebesgue outer measure?

Comment: 'We cannot conclude that $\int_{[0,1]^2} f =0$' doesn't mean that the integral has  a value different from $0$. It could also mean that the integral is not defined.

Comment: As geetha290krm recalled, the post you linked to ([False beliefs about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93865/false-beliefs-about-lebesgue-measure-on-mathbbr)) already answered your question, which I am therefore voting to close as a duplicate of it.